# How to set position absolute in tailwind in relation with another div?

Tags: tailwind-css

I got a simple code as such :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="w-2/3 h-32 bg-gray-900 text-yellow-500 relative">
  <span class="absolute top-96 left-full">hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However the `hello` is way outside the `div` I intend to use it in.
How can I put `hello` inside my 2nd `div`?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @AmirhosseinShahbazi Nope. No difference.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I put hello inside my 2nd div?

`absolute top-96 left-full` positions the `<span>hello</span>` `24rem` below the top and on the right edge of the `<div class="w-2/3 h-32 bg-gray-900 text-yellow-500 relative">...</div>`. Remove `absolute top-96 left-full` from the `span` and "hello" will appear within the bounds of the `bg-gray-900` `div`.